# captureMediaStream() on a video element the mediaStreamTrack ended event doesn't fire?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am using WebRTC API to implement screen sharing and media file play,I am successfully able to share the screen and listen the mediaStreamTrack ended event.But I am successfully able to play media file on WebRTC, yet I cannot listen the mediaStreamTrack ended event(not fired).So I cannot change to webcam, I don't know when the file has played to the end.

```
_setScreenEndedListener(track) {
    track.addEventListener('ended', () => {
        this.removeLocalVideo(true);
        logger.warn('#screen sharing stoped !!');
        this.emit('screen-sharing-stop');
    });
}
```

Above is the way I listen the event. I think there is no problem.But the media file played on the  element and **video.captureStream() generate the stream whose streamTrack can not fire the ended event when the media file gose to the file end**.I don't know whether it's a bug or something else, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, even though your media playback has ended, your MediaStream is still alive, this is because you may very well want to display an other media from this same stream (which Chrome doesn't support...) or simply set it back to an other currentTime so it does loop:

```js
source.onplaying = e => {
  source.onplaying = null;
  target.srcObject = source.captureStream ? source.captureStream() : source.mozCaptureStream ? source.mozCaptureStream() : console.error('unsupported browser');
  target.play();
};
source.onended = e => {
  console.log('Ended. Looping back in time.');
  source.load();
  source.play();
}
source.play();
```

```css
video{
  max-width: 48vw;
}
```

```html
<video id="target" muted></video>
<video id="source" crossorigin controls
  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm.480p.webm#t=25"></video>
```

So in your situation, the event you want to listen to is the one of the MediaElement (e.g `<video>`)  instead of the one of the MediaStream.